# Laravel cache clear parameter by subkey

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use Laravel 5 cache in te following way:

```
public function putUserCacheData($key, $value){
    \Cache::put($this->login, [$key => $value], 30);
}
```

So I have structure like this

```
    ['testlogin'] => [
                  'param1' => 'value1',
                  'param2' => 'value2',
                 ]
```

But I can dlete Item from cache with key param1 for testlogin?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cache tags to do this.

```
public function putUserCacheData($key, $value){
    \Cache::tags($this->login)->put($key, $value, 30);
}

// Remove all entries
Cache::tags($this->login)->flush();

// Remove only param1
Cache::tags($this->login)->forget('param1');
```

But note that cache tags are not supported when using the file or database cache drivers.

Comment: I was using file cache driver, will try now your example with redis, thnx!

Comment: For testing you can use **array** cache driver if you don't have redis or memcache installed.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Cache::forget('testlogin.param1')
```

**EDIT**

You're right - we cannot use dot notation. So only one thing that you can do is to:

```
$testlogin = Cache::get('testlogin');
unset(testlogin['param1']);
Cache::put('testlogin', $testlogin);
```

Comment: You can't use dot notation with cache by default

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunely u can't do it with scratch laravel 5.*. It's better to use database or if its temp data u can easily do it with Sessions:

```
Session::put('some', ['data' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2']);

Session::forget('some.data');

return Session::get('some');
```

Comment: Session or database is not cache.

Comment: @TheFallen i give him variants. He cant do it with cache in scratch laravel.

Comment: @TheFallen I know about tags, see his question, its not about using tags. It's about alternative of section function in laravel 4.

Comment: It says Laravel 5 in his question.